# What is the correct kanji for the verb to sweat 汗をかく

Tags: kanji, verbs

What is the character used for the verb to sweat?  汗をかく

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kanji is 掻. Let me describe how you can check.

When you type the expression in with your IME, often a dictionary with appear with usage information. On my system, when I type かく, to the side a window with details on 掻く, 書く, 描く, and 搔く appears. For 掻く it says: （頭・あぐら・汗・いびき・裏・寝首・恥・べそを）⇒かく　＊掻く：常用外 ＊簡易慣用字体

Note arrow suggesting that it be written in hiragana. Also note the * which indicates that it is not included in basic kanji, and hence is not typically written in kanji.

Also, the [dictionary](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E6%8E%BB%E3%81%8F&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0na) is often useful. Quote:

> か・く【×掻く】
>
> ② 涙や汗などをからだの外に出す。「寝汗を―・く」「べそを―・く」

Note the × before the headword. This indicates that it is not generally written in kanji. Same details as above.

Comment: Thanks for that. (my IME didn't have sweat come up under this character which is why I asked.)